# "Exactly one event of A_1,...,A_n occurs" using set operations?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm supposed to describe the situation using set theoretical operators $(\cup, \cap,\setminus,$ etc.). So we have $A_1,..,A_n$ events and **only one** of them occurs. I know that $A^c_n$ means $A_n$ does **not** occur. So I'm supposed to combine, let's say, $A_1$ with $n$ events that do not occur, correct? I'm not so sure about how to express that. I know for example, $(A_1 \cup ... \cup A_n)$ means at least one event occurs.

Does that mean the solution here is $(A_1 \cup A^c_2\cup ... \cup A^c_n )$?

Comment: Isn't this true when both $A_1,A_2$ occur? Look at the [XOR operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or).

Comment: So you mean  (A_1 ∩ (A^c)_2 ∩ ... ∩ (A^c)_n )?

Comment: Yes, that is one term. But alternatively, in case $A_2$ happens, we want $A_1^c\cap A_2\cap A_3^c...\cap A_n^c$. Similary when $A_3$ happens and the rest don't. Just add all these terms.

Comment: Thank you. How do I mark my question as answered?

Comment: Uhm...if you find any of the answers helpful, you can accept them by clicking the tick mark button next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: you want $A_1 \cup \ldots \cup A_n$, but you do not want $(A_1 \cap A_2) \cup \ldots $

Answer (score 1):

You can read $\cup$ like "or", $\cap$ like "and" and $\cdot^c$ like "not".

So what you want to say is "$A_1$ happens and none of $A_2,\dots, A_n$ happens **or** $A_2$ happens and none of $A_1, A_3,\dots, A_n$ happens **or** $\dots$ **or** $A_n$ happens and none of $A_1,\dots, A_{n-1}$ happens."

Translate this into the set-theoretical writing and you obtain $$(A_1\cap (A_2\cup \dots \cup A_n)^c) \cup (A_2\cap (A_1\cup A_3\cup \dots \cup A_n)^c \cup\dots \cup (A_n\cap (A_1\cup \dots \cup A_{n-1})^c).$$

You can of course rewrite this using the usual rules of set-theory.